# C++ epoll with container_of

Tags: c++, epoll

I was wondering how one might set up epoll with container_of.  I am using latest version of ubuntu with eclipse-cdt (gcc).  My idea was to grab the events, and then grab the container the events came from.

If I have a struct like so:

```
struct client {
   int s;
   struct epoll_event e;
}foo;
```

and then ... :

```
struct epoll_event *events = NULL;
struct client *c = NULL;
foo.s = (socket);
int efd = epoll_create1(0);
foo.e.data.fd = foo.s;
foo.e.events = EPOLLIN;
epoll_ctl ( efd , EPOLL_CTL_ADD , foo.s , &foo.e );
events = (struct epoll_event*)calloc ( XXX , sizeof event );
while(1) {
    int n = epoll_wait ( efd , events , XXX , -1 );
    for ( int i = 0 ; i  < n ; i++ ) {
        c = container_of ( events[i] , client , e );
```

How can I do something like this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all `events[i]` is not a pointer. To get a pointer either use `events + i` or `&events[i]`.

Secondly, the `epoll_event` structures in the array is not the same as the `epoll_event` structures in the `client` structure, which means you can't use `container_of`.

A valid example of the `container_of` usage:

```
client c;
epoll_event *ep = &c.e;

client *cp = container_of(ep, client, e);
```

As you can see, the first argument must point to an *actual* member in the "container" you want to reach. After this `cp` will point to `c`.

In your case you want to take a pointer (and as I said above, is not actually a pointer) that *does not* point to a member in the `client` structure, and that will not work.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, events[0] (which is an event) is not a "struct epoll_event"?  I see how the container_of is working, do you have any idea how I can achieve what I want to do?

Comment: @Ohmages `events[0]` is not a _pointer_. And more importantly, it's not a pointer to a member of the `client` structure.

Comment: Ah, I getcha.  Hmmm.  Well, this certainly puts a bump in the road.  I was hoping there would be some sort of way to-do what I wanted.  Thank you for your response.  It may not have been what I wanted to see, but at least container_of is all cleared up now! :)